# The number of boxes in the plane which intersect with lines

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

For any $n\in\mathbb{N}_+$, let $\{M_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of integers and  $\{x_{k}^{(n)}\}_{k=1}^{M_n}\subset[0,1]$ be $M_n$ real numbers such that
$$|x_i^{(n)}-x_j^{(n)}|>\frac{1}{2^n},\ \text{for}\ i\neq j.$$

Let $\mathcal{C}_n\subset\{[\frac{k}{2^n},\frac{k+1}{2^n}]|k=0,1,\cdots,2^n-1\}$, denote by $C_n$ the number of elements of the class $\mathcal{C}_n$, be of the properties:

（1） $\mathcal{C}_n$ has positive density, i.e., there exists a positive constant $C$ without depending on $n$, such that $\frac{C_n}{2^n}>C$;

（2） for any $I\in\mathcal{C}_n$, there exists an interval $J\in\mathcal{C}_{n-1}$ such that $I\subset J$.

Through out any point $(0,x_k^{(n)})$ in the plane, there exists a line $l_{x_k^{(n)}}$:
$$y=K_{x_k^{(n)}}\cdot x+x_k^{(n)},$$
where the slope $K_{x_k^{(n)}}\in[0,1]$, for any $k,n$. Thus for any $n$, we have $M_n$ lines.

Write
$$B_n=\Big\{\Delta\times[\frac{i}{2^n},\frac{i+1}{2^n}]|\Delta\in\mathcal{C}_n,i\in\mathbb{Z}\Big\}.$$
Let $L_n$ be the number of boxes in $B_n$ for which intersect with some lines above.

QUESTION: Is there a positive real number $D$ such that for any $n\geq 1$,
$$L_n\geq DM_nC_n?$$

Comment: I think this question would really benefit from an example.